# How to keep hamburger icon without visible appBar flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, opacity, flutter-appbar

I recently tried keeping a Hamburger icon for my menu slider without an AppBar or at least completely invisible. The first attempt was with a SafeArea but that emptied Scaffold. Then I tried setting the Opacity to 0.0 like shown on the code below. But it gives out the same result as SafeArea with nothing on Scaffold. Please can anyone help?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        // Define the default Brightness and Colors
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
        accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          Opacity(
            opacity: 0.0,
            appBar: AppBar(),
          ),
          drawer: new Drawer(
            child: new ListView(),
          ),
          body: new Center(
              child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[],
          ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

If I have understood you well, you want to display a menu button to show the `Drawer` without displaying any `AppBar`.

One option is to use a `Stack` for the body of the `Scaffold`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        // Define the default Brightness and Colors
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
        accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new ListView(),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Center(
                child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[],
            )),
            Positioned(
              left: 10,
              top: 20,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () => scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Note for Newbie like me: I used the above approach on a stateless widget, stuffs broke when coming back from a newly navigated page. "the getter 'usergesture progress' was called on null" was the error. things worked fine when the widget was changed to a stateful widget.

Comment: I am getting NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'openDrawer'

Answer (score 7):

If I have understood your question well.

You have your own custom Menu button to open/close drawer.
You don't want to use AppBar as well.

In that case you can use `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>()` object to open Drawer.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldState = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldState,
  drawer: DrawerView(),
  body: ThemeScreen(
    header: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 15),
          onPressed: (){
            _scaffoldState.currentState.openDrawer();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make AppBar completely invisible by setting the same color and elevation = 0
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8SHM.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF198BAA),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF198BAA),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item1'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The Appbar will come in between if there is a scrollable content in the Scaffold's body.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Ox.S's answer, but you can make the AppBar transparent and then change the icon to whatever color you want.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0.0,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
  ),
  drawer: Drawer(...
```